# How to query in json start with same name key using json query?

Tags: json-query

I have below json i want to take out all the macaddress list in one jason array how do i do ?

```
{
  "facts_hash": {
    "lib": "/usr/share/fdi/facts:/opt/extension/facts",
    "interfaces": "eno1,eno2,eno3,eno4,eno5,eno6,ens3f0,ens3f1,lo",
    "ipaddress_eno1": "192.168.101.135",
    "macaddress_eno1": "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3c",
    "netmask_eno1": "255.255.255.0",
    "mtu_eno1": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno2": "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3d",
    "mtu_eno2": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno3": "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3e",
    "mtu_eno3": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno4": "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3f",
    "mtu_eno4": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno5": "b8:83:03:81:4b:20",
    "mtu_eno5": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno6": "b8:83:03:81:4b:21",
    "mtu_eno6": "1500",
    "macaddress_ens3f0": "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c",
    "mtu_ens3f0": "1500",
    "macaddress_ens3f1": "b8:83:03:84:d5:1d",

  },
  "name": "daisy-joni-selitto-quinto",
  "id": 269
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jq does the trick as recommended by jack.. and here is the clear jq expression..

jq '[.facts_hash | to_entries[] | select(.key|startswith("macaddress_")).value]'

Thanks Jack once again for your help..

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jq, this expression

```
 [.facts_hash[]|  to_entries[] | select(.key|startswith("mac")).value]
```

should output this array:

```
[
  "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3c",
  "b8:83:03:81:4b:21",
  "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c",
  "b8:83:03:84:d5:1d"
]
```

Another option would be to convert the json to xml and use xpath on it.

Comment: Thanks Jack for your reply, i tried the same on https://jqplay.org/ but getting error

Comment: @BharatGupta Part of the problem may be that the json in the question is invalid. Try it [on a json validator like this one](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Hi Jack Thanks.. jq '[.facts_hash | to_entries[] | select(.key|startswith("macaddress_")).value]'  like this and it retuns the expected reult..

Comment: @BharatGupta It seems to be the same expression, doesn't it?

Comment: jack in your expression there was [ ] bracket after the .facts_hash, i just removed that and it works.

Comment: @BharatGupta Interesting! In theory, it shouldn't work without the brackets (it definitely works with them when I try it). It shows again how fickle jq, jsonpath, etc. are and how much they depend on where they are used. That's why I prefer working with xml and xpath...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to iterate key in object, `startsWith` to check macadress text and use `reduce` to output your requirement as

```
var result = Object.keys(obj.facts_hash).reduce((acc, item)=>{
  if(item.startsWith("macaddress")) console.log(obj.facts_hash[item]);
}, []);
```

or

```
  var result = Object.keys(obj.facts_hash).reduce((acc, item) => {
                if (item.startsWith("macaddress")) {
                    //console.log(obj.facts_hash[item]);
                    acc.push(obj.facts_hash[item]);
                }
                return acc;
            }, []);
  console.log(result);
```

```js
var obj = {
  "facts_hash": {
    "lib": "/usr/share/fdi/facts:/opt/extension/facts",
    "interfaces": "eno1,eno2,eno3,eno4,eno5,eno6,ens3f0,ens3f1,lo",
    "ipaddress_eno1": "192.168.101.135",
    "macaddress_eno1": "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3c",
    "netmask_eno1": "255.255.255.0",
    "mtu_eno1": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno2": "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3d",
    "mtu_eno2": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno3": "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3e",
    "mtu_eno3": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno4": "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3f",
    "mtu_eno4": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno5": "b8:83:03:81:4b:20",
    "mtu_eno5": "1500",
    "macaddress_eno6": "b8:83:03:81:4b:21",
    "mtu_eno6": "1500",
    "macaddress_ens3f0": "b8:83:03:84:d5:1c",
    "mtu_ens3f0": "1500",
    "macaddress_ens3f1": "b8:83:03:84:d5:1d",

  },
  "name": "daisy-joni-selitto-quinto",
  "id": 269
}


var result = Object.keys(obj.facts_hash).reduce((acc, item)=>{
  if(item.startsWith("macaddress")) console.log(obj.facts_hash[item]);
}, []);

//console.log(result);
```